# Rails 3 application creates sessions only for certain users in my db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

This is an extremely weird situation. I have a Rails 3 app that authenticates users using OmniAuth. The problem I recently encountered is that after correctly validating a user using the aforementioned gem, at some part of the code I set some session variables, specifically:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

The problem is, that this line only works for some users (it does not depend on the browser, the cookies, nothing, only for certain users. The `user` variable is valid and has an `id` attribute, but this session variable does not persist on the next request, sending this user back to the login page. Again, this only happens to some users, which makes the problem a whole lot more difficult to debug.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

PS: I've tried using the cookie session store and the database session store, both with the same results.

**EDIT**: The problem ended up being something completely not related to sessions.

Comment: What happens if you put the user.id in the flash and show it in the view? Does it persist then?